# Forbidden "Object" ... is under active Temporary hold and cannot be deleted, overwritten or archived until hold is removed

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I had uploaded some objects on google cloud storage for which I get the error as `Forbidden Object Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError`. Additionally, I do not have full rights to Cloud Storage as I am working on the university class project.

Can you please tell me how to delete the objects? I was the one to upload it using the Google API. The interesting thing to note is that other files I can delete but three files that I uploaded were written protected if I remember correctly and cannot be deleted now.

### Here is the additional context to the issue.

I checked the retention policy for the storage bucket. It has no retention policy enabled, as can be seen from the output below
`gsutil retention get gs://cs291project2`

> gs://cs291project2/ has no Retention Policy.

Yet, the remove command doesn't seem to work.

`SISProject2$ gsutil rm gs://cs291project2/**`

> Removing >gs://cs291project2/00/00/3Da608e50745f7fe13116e728cd0282fda42ce3f83d3f509d5a83f4cd5>80...
> AccessDeniedException: 403 Object >'cs291project2/00/00/3Da608e50745f7fe13116e728cd0282fda42ce3f83d3f509d5a83f4cd580' >is under active Temporary hold and cannot be deleted, overwritten or archived until >hold is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message `Object Temporary Hold.. is under active hold` you might have uploaded a file to a locked, retention-enabled bucket. You can check if you have the retention policy enabled for the bucket by running these commands:

**Example:**

```sh
$ gsutil retention get gs://bucket
    Retention Policy (LOCKED):
       Duration: 7 Day(s)
       Effective Time: Thu, 11 Sep 2021 19:52:15 GMT
```

**Example:**

```sh
$ gsutil ls -Lb gs://bucket/object
    gs://bucket/object:
      Creation time:          Thu, 27 Sep 2020 00:00:00 GMT
      Update time:            Thu, 27 Sep 2021 12:11:00 GMT
      Event-Based Hold:       Enabled
```

If that is the case, you cannot delete the object until its retention period is reached.

If you receive a `403` error whilst running these commands, you most likely do not have the correct permission configured. You can run the command below to review the policies for the project. Please note, this is a permissions-based command.

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <project-id> | grep 'role\|user\|members'
```

You can then compare the result against the [IAM permissions for gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil). For example, the `gsutil rm` command requires these:

```
rm      Buckets     storage.buckets.delete
                    storage.objects.delete
                    storage.objects.list
rm      Objects     storage.objects.delete
                    storage.objects.get
```

As a last resort, to drill down further to see what might be happening you can add the `-D` switch to run the command in debug mode.

```sh
gsutil -D retention get gs://bucket
```

Please note, this comes with a warning:

```sh
***************************** WARNING *****************************
*** You are running gsutil with debug output enabled.
*** Be aware that debug output includes authentication credentials.
*** Make sure to remove the value of the Authorization header for
*** each HTTP request printed to the console prior to posting to
*** a public medium such as a forum post or Stack Overflow.
***************************** WARNING *****************************
```

Comment: ```$ gsutil rm gs://cs291project2/**```

```Removing gs://cs291project2/00/00/3Da608e50745f7fe13116e728cd0282fda42ce3f83d3f509d5a83f4cd580...```
AccessDeniedException: 403 Object 'cs291project2/00/00/3Da608e50745f7fe13116e728cd0282fda42ce3f83d3f509d5a83f4cd580' is under active Temporary hold and cannot be deleted, overwritten or archived until hold is removed.

```gsutil retention get gs://cs291project2```
gs://cs291project2/ has no Retention Policy.

Comment: Seems the bucket has no retention policy :(

Comment: I have added some extra information the Answer

Comment: Yup you are right, I don't have access to the bucket due to different policy setting. Thanks a lot for the inputs helped in getting things clarified